# I want to create a new tag

Tags: discussion, support, feature-request, tagging

I Want to create a new tag "Indian Entrance Examination Problem", which will contains problems that has come to different Indian Entrance Examinations. Most of the Indian Students used to ask such type of problems and lot of problems has been already discussed. Should I do it? How to do ? Is my reputation enough to do that? If I am not eligible please some of you help a little to do it.

I have one more future request. One should enter the source of the problem when he post it. One new box should appear in the ask question form.

Answer (score 10):

Downvotes on meta  mean disagreement:  in this case,  with the proposal to introduce the particular  tag. Besides being too long (there's 25 character limit), it would not serve the purpose for which tags are introduced: describe what the question is about.

The existence of such meta-tags is problematic, because they allow users to circumvent classifying their question by subject. There are already [hundreds of questions](http://data.stackexchange.com/mathematics/query/152366/recent-questions-with-only-one-tag) on which [homework](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homework) is the only tag. This is despite a warning not to do this, which appears in the homework tag excerpt. The official SE stance is that [meta-tags should die](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/).  If I had my druthers,   [homework](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homework) would die too.

As for providing the source:  it can be done at the bottom of question body. SE is unlikely to introduce a special box for this field. Most SE questions are not assigned to the user by someone; they arise in the process of user's work (e.g., programmers working on a  company  project). Such users  would not be willing to disclose what exactly they are doing, which is not a problem as long as they state a clear, self-contained question. A famous recent example is [How can I connect to a Tor hidden service using curl in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15445285)

Comment: +1 for the famous example. Didn't know about that story!